# How to develop a highly secured web-based user login system in JSP?

Tags: oracle, security, jsp

I am developing a web based application using JSP and ORACLE. The application will allow some 20 specific users around the globe using www, http. They will login using username and password pre - defined by me. What strategy I should take to disallow any unauthorized user to enter into the system. If such thread already exists here, then please suggest the best one. Any sort of help is welcome

Comment: If security is your goal you should only use `https:`, not `http:`

Comment: Do you need any further help with this? Let me know and I'll update my answer if so.

Answer (score 1):

There are several measures you can take :

- complicated passwords
- hash password in the database using something like SHA
- make use of HTTPS protocol
- never send clear passwords to user
- maybe block an account when X login attempts failed
- use of prepared statements when querying your DB
- make error messages as standard as possible (don't inform if the password was wrong or the username doesn't exist, just provide a generic error)
- ...

That's actually a very broad question, security can get pretty high depending on the needs.

Comment: Don't block a user's account. That allows a DOS attack on a particular user. Instead, use tarpit or captcha. Also, log, alert admin, and alert user to attempted access. The rest is good.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how important your data is and who you are trying to secure it against (e.g. if it is a bank you might not allow passwords to be reset by a password reset email, but for most other applications this may be fine). However, I've included some basic pointers below.

- Use HTTPS for every URL.
- Implement [HSTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security).
- Mark all cookies as [secure](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SecureFlag) and [HTTP only](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly).
- Enforce strong passwords.
- Log every login attempt (at least date/time, username, remote IP and whether successful)
- Store passwords using [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) or [something arguably more secure](http://www.unlimitednovelty.com/2012/03/dont-use-bcrypt.html).
- If there are X failed login attempts from the same IP in the last Y minutes, add an artificial delay to requests from this IP to hinder a brute force attack.
- If there are X failed login attempts against the same username in the last Y minutes, add an artificial delay for this username hinder a brute force attack.
- For the artificial delays make them cross-thread to stop concurrent requests.
- Also delay even if the username doesn't exists to protect against [username enumeration](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_User_Enumeration_and_Guessable_User_Account_%28OWASP-AT-002%29).
- Protect against other forms of [username enumeration](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_User_Enumeration_and_Guessable_User_Account_%28OWASP-AT-002%29)
- Implement a policy where passwords are never output anywhere.